# getting data frame names from list inside a loop

Tags: r

I retrieve all dataframes from environment and then do some stuff:

```
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

names(dfs)

"customers"
"sales"
"campaigns"
```

First thing I need to extract is object name inside a loop:

```
for (df in dfs) {
  df_name <- deparse(substitute(df))
  # do some stuff
  # do some more stuff
  print(df_name)
}
```

But instead data frame names to operate I get:

```
"df"
"df"
"df"
```

I've tested a function inside the loop too:

```
find_name <- function(df) {
  df_name_is <- substitute(df)
  return(df_name_is)
}
```

But the output is:

```
df
df
df
```

looping through `names` of df gets me the `colnames` of every df, not the df name itself.

any hint will be much appreciated

Comment: looping through names of df gets me the colnames of every df

Comment: bouncyball `print(df)` returns the complete content for every df but I just need the name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind use loop by counter (length) instead of names this is a valid approach:

```
for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {

print(names(dfs)[i])

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about iterating over the names?!

```
for (df_name in names(dfs)) {
  print(df_name)
  df_obj <- dfs[[df_nmae]]
}
```